# Check if a string has multiple commas next to each other c++

Tags: c++, string, loops

I have ~ 3 million strings that look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7) VALUES(1,'STRING','STRING',,,'STRING','STRING');
```

I need to write a script to find all instances where there are multiple commas next to each other and insert `null` in between them.

I have tried looping through the string and checking each character but I would like a faster solution.

This is my current (proposed but slow) solution:

```
char last_char = line.at(0);
for(std::string::iterator i = line.begin(); i != line.end(); ++i) {
    char current_char = line[i];
    if(current_char == ',' && last_char == ',') {
        //Insert null here
    }
    last_char = current_char;
}
```

The solution should preferably be fast as I have roughly 3m lines that I need to convert.

To sum it all up, after the script runs the strings should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7) VALUES(1, 'STRING', 'STRING', null, null, 'STRING', 'STRING');
```

Comment: Shouldn't your "proposed" solution be `if(current_char == ',' && last_char == ',') {` to check for consecutive commas instead of single quotes?

Comment: You can use Regex to look for patterns in strings. It's a bit confusing if you're unfamiliar with it, but you can find more info [here](https://regexone.com/)

Regex.Replace() is what you're looking for here.

Comment: @scohe001 Yes, it should be, thanks you for correcting that

Comment: Unless you are splitting strings, why insert a null rather than a space character between commas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string newString = Regex.Replace(inString, ",(?=,)", ", null");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What do I need to include to use this?

Comment: System.Text.RegularExpressions

Comment: @emsimpson92 it looks like that is using .NET.  Can I use it on ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, you can use it on ubuntu. I thought this was a C# question. Either way, regex works for C++, you'll just need `#Include<regex>`

Comment: [Here's a link if you wanted more info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) --- [This should help you understand how you can use it. It's really a powerful tool](https://regexone.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
auto pos = line.find(",,");
while (pos != std::string::npos)
{
    line.replace(pos, 1, ",null");
    pos = line.find(",,", pos+5);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/r6S3At)